# Cryptography Padding is invalid exception

Tags: vb.net, exception, visual-studio-2012, cryptography, deserialization

I am using Visual Basic.net and have the following System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException exception:

> Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.

Here is my code:

```
    Public Sub SaveEncryptedObjectToFile(FileName As String, Item As Object)
    Dim fs As FileStream
    Dim encryptor As CryptoStream

    Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter

    Dim password As String = "MyPassword"
    Dim salt As String = "InitialVector123"

    Dim AES As AesManaged = New AesManaged
    AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC

    Dim HashAlgorithm As String = "SHA1" 'Can be SHA1 or MD5
    Dim PasswordIterations As Integer = 2
    Dim InitialVector As String = "InitialVector123" 'This should be a string of 16 ASCII characters.
    Dim KeySize As Integer = 256 'Can be 128, 192, or 256.

    Dim InitialVectorBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InitialVector)
    Dim SaltValueBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt)
    Dim DerivedPassword As PasswordDeriveBytes = New PasswordDeriveBytes(password, SaltValueBytes, HashAlgorithm, PasswordIterations)
    Dim KeyBytes As Byte() = DerivedPassword.GetBytes(CInt(KeySize / 8))

    Dim encryptTransf As ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateEncryptor(KeyBytes, InitialVectorBytes)

    fs = New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create)
    encryptor = New CryptoStream(fs, encryptTransf, CryptoStreamMode.Write)

    Try
        formatter.Serialize(encryptor, Item)
    Catch e As SerializationException
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " & e.Message)
        Throw
    Finally
        fs.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Public Function OpenEncryptedObjectFromFile(FileName As String) As Object
    Dim fs As New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open)
    Dim decryptor As CryptoStream

    Dim ItemToReturn As New Object

    Dim password As String = "MyPassword"
    Dim salt As String = "InitialVector123"

    Dim AES As AesManaged = New AesManaged
    AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC

    Dim HashAlgorithm As String = "SHA1" 'Can be SHA1 or MD5
    Dim PasswordIterations As Integer = 2
    Dim InitialVector As String = "InitialVector123" 'This should be a string of 16 ASCII characters.
    Dim KeySize As Integer = 256 'Can be 128, 192, or 256.

    Dim InitialVectorBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InitialVector)
    Dim SaltValueBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt)
    Dim DerivedPassword As PasswordDeriveBytes = New PasswordDeriveBytes(password, SaltValueBytes, HashAlgorithm, PasswordIterations)
    Dim KeyBytes As Byte() = DerivedPassword.GetBytes(CInt(KeySize / 8))
    'Dim KeyBytes As Byte() = Rfc2898DeriveBytes(CInt(KeySize / 8))

    Dim decryptTrans As ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateDecryptor(KeyBytes, InitialVectorBytes)

    Try
        Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter

        decryptor = New CryptoStream(fs, decryptTrans, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
        ItemToReturn = DirectCast(formatter.Deserialize(decryptor), Object)
        Return ItemToReturn
    Catch e As SerializationException
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to deserialize. Reason: " & e.Message)
        Throw
    Finally
        fs.Close()
    End Try
End Function
```

The exception occurs at the following line:

```
ItemToReturn = DirectCast(formatter.Deserialize(decryptor), Object)
```

I am not sure if this has any relation to the CryptographicException, but I am currently getting the following warning:

> 'Public Overrides Function GetBytes(cb As Integer) As Byte()' is obsolete: 'Rfc2898DeriveBytes replaces PasswordDeriveBytes for deriving key material from a password and is preferred in new applications.'.

At this line:

```
Dim KeyBytes As Byte() = DerivedPassword.GetBytes(CInt(KeySize / 8))
```

I have had a look online and cannot find any working solution for this warning.

Answer (score 0):

In order to diagnose the problem, you need to see what is being produced.  Change the decryption side to expect no padding.  That will allow it to run past the exception and produce something.

You can then examine the output to help diagnose the problem.  As a first guess I would check your keys.  Make sure that the encryption key is byte for byte the same as the decryption key.  Mismatched keys are one of the possible causes of the padding error you are getting.

Comment: OK, thank you. I have turned the padding off. Now a file is saved and the file can be decrypted. What padding do you recommend?

Comment: PKCS7 is fine for padding.  Do **not** leave padding off, it masks a real problem.  Padding is removed after decryption, not before so you have some other problem somewhere.  Did you check the keys?